# Random Forest Classifier - OutOfMemoryError - PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Random Forest Classifier for a text dataset(approx 60Mb).

I am making my features from hashing TF like -

```
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures")
features = hashingTF.transform(removeStopwords)

rb = RandomForestClassifier().setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("labels")
```

After that I am making a pipeline and creating a model using my training data. But when I run my code I am getting following error -

```
18/02/09 14:31:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 9 contains a task of very large size (42550 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
18/02/09 14:47:20 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$anonfun$5.apply(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$anonfun$5.apply(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.allocateNewChunkIfNeeded(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.write(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Utils.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1337)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyStream(Utils.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
18/02/09 14:47:20 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$anonfun$5.apply(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$anonfun$5.apply(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.allocateNewChunkIfNeeded(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.write(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Utils.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1337)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyStream(Utils.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
18/02/09 14:47:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

But when I change this line -
`hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=2000)` then Random Classifier is working.

Do any body know what I need to do to solve this error because default numFeatures for HashingTF is 2^20 and I am restricting it to only 2000 and this reduces my accuracy.

Same code I tried with Naive Bayes and LinearSVC it is working fine without limiting numFeatures in HashingTF but my accuracy is coming only 60%. So I want to check with RFC to increase accuracy.

I even tried to increase the heap size by this -

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m
```

But this is also not helping me.

Comment: The first line of your log suggest you need to increase the number of partitions used by your RDD: `rdd1 = rdd.repartition(200)`

Comment: @Jaco Repartitioning will solve this problem?

Comment: Repartitioning should definitely help. That error message is usually raised when your partition size is too  large.